# where i can find substitute of red5plugin link?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, red5

i want to add red5plugin to my eclipse, I find a tutorial like this:
http://robsilverton.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/getting-up-and-nearly-running-with-the-red5-eclipse-plug-in/

but, the link for software update was broken. is there any one know about the substitution ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[red5-ide-plugin](http://www.red5.org/red5-ide-plugin/)

[CreatingRed5Projects](http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Red5Plugin/CreatingRed5Projects)